# I want to extract today's date and if today's date is friday then do (today-3) else (today-11)

Tags: postgresql

I want to extract today's date and if today's date is friday then do (today-3) else (today-11) and use the result of this query in below delete statement

here is my query:

```
Delete from table where date<(above result)

select now()::timestamp::date; this statement will give me the today's date
select to_char(now()::timestamp::date, 'dy') this will give me week day in string
select extract(dow from now()::timestamp) this will give me week day in integer
```

How can I combine these things to achive my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
select case extract(dow from current_date) when 5 
         then (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 day') 
         else
         CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '11 day' end
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/6077)**

Answer (score 0):

Rahul's Answer is correct but if you want't to go with your way
then you can use `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN extract(dow from now()::timestamp) = 5 
                  THEN (select now()::timestamp::date) - 3 
                  ELSE (select now()::timestamp::date) - 11 
        END
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  CASE extract(dow FROM CURRENT_DATE)
      WHEN 5
        THEN (CURRENT_DATE - '3 day'::INTERVAL)
      ELSE CURRENT_DATE - '11 day'::INTERVAL
  END
```